# passing empty queryset to form results in form_invalid

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model form that contains among other things a dropdown list of pupils (`ModelMultipleChoiceField`), which is initially empty but when a user selects a teacher, I get the list of pupils registered for this teacher via ajax request.

```
        self.fields['pupil'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Pupil.objects.none(),)
```

Everything works till the validation. Since initially queryset points to none, when a form is submitted it is returned with an error "It is invalid choice".

I can pass the entire set of pupils to the `pupil` field and then make it empty via jQuery but that looks ugly. What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: You either need to do second request for teacher's pupils or get all of them in first request and after that filter by teach in js.

Comment: can you use clean_pupil method for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows. In this case first we render the form with empty queryset after you loading the choices with ajax. you will submit data with a post request. when we receive the `POST` request we are sending full queryset to the form.
In above case you explained the queryset is empty so you have got validation error as invalid choice. But, in this case we have full queryset so, it will work perfectly.

views.py

```
def sample_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        queryset = Pupil.objects.all()
        form = SampleForm(request.POST, queryset=queryset)
        # your code goes here
    else:
        queryset = Pupil.objects.none()
        form = SampleForm(queryset=queryset)
        # your code goes here
```

forms.py

```
class SampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
       queryset = kwargs.pop('queryset', None)
       super(SampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['pupil'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=queryset)
       # your code
```